# How can I change encoding in SOAP xml header?

Tags: asp.net, soap, encoding, utf-8, asmx

I need to create SOAP request with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
```

line using ASP .Net but at all web services that can be found in Web I see only

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

examples.

I added

```
<globalization responseHeaderEncoding="windows-1251" fileEncoding="windows-1251" requestEncoding="windows-1251"
 responseEncoding="windows-1251" />
```

to Web.config and it gave effect (UTF-8 characters now break my service) but browser still shows utf-8 [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7LBV.png)

Maybe this interface always shows only a UTF-8? I did not find a single example where he showed something else. You can search examples in Google with "The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response" request.

Comment: I saw one thread that said it can't be changed. I searched `asmx change response encoding`. But there are a lot of similar and related questions to check out. Have you looked into changing it after it's returned? (I have no idea if it's possible.)

Comment: Check final response [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1109783.aspx?Change+web+service+xml+encoding+type+not+getting+any+help).